# Finding Out if Traffic Comes for Google Ads iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, google-ads-api

I'm trying to run Universal App Campaigns for my iOS App with Google Ads. And I would like to show them a specific page in the app for those who came from the UA Campaign, deep linking is not possible with Universal App Campaigns, so is there a way to track if the install came from Google Ads? Right now we use Firebase for tracking Installs.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution? We're facing same question now.